# solr: how to keep duplication content of different URLs

Tags: solr, digest, duplicate-content

We have some webpages having similar pages of same content (such as UPS mgmt consoles) within our internal network.
solr always keeps only one of them because they have the same digest.

```
    Indexer: finished at 2013-11-18 01:21:28, elapsed: 00:00:02
    SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2013-11-18 01:21:28
    SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_test5
    SolrDeleteDuplicates: deleting 4 duplicates
    SolrDeleteDuplicates: finished at 2013-11-18 01:21:29, elapsed: 00:00:01
    crawl finished: crawl
```

All the 4 deleted duplicates are of different urls. I want to keep all of them in solr while solr can still delete the other kinds of duplicate content.
I guess the url isn't used to generate the digest by default so is there any way to set to use the url? What other options do I have?